# Integration Tests in Elixir - how to filter out from Unit Tests

Tags: testing, elixir

I want to separate out Integration tests from Unit Tests in Elixir. I found the [Elixir mix documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/mix/) has a section on filters, and describes just what I want to do.

Then add the lines below into appdir/test/test_helper.exs

```
# Exclude all external tests from running  
ExUnit.configure exclude: [external: true]
```

Then how does one tag tests as "external"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just add `@tag external: true` (or the shortcut `@tag :external`) before the test definition (you can also use `@moduletag` to tag a whole test case).

Comment: Works well thanks. And for anyone reading, "mix test --include external:true" runs all tests.